# install or compile apache php from sources on separate servers

Tags: php, apache, docker

I would like to know how to compile apache & php on separate servers since we need reference of apache while compiling php.

I have installed apache2 from source on one ubuntu machine, say "server1".
I want to install php from source on another ubuntu machine, say "server2".
The configure command for php on "server2" is

**./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql**

where --with-apxs2 points to the local apache file system but my apache file system is on different machine server1.

I am trying this solution in **Docker** where hub has number of ready made LAMP server ready for use. But I want to try it compiling from source on separate docker containers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered the official php image in the docker registry? It's designed to help you build your own image, if if you choose not to use it the approach is useful to emulate: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: I will use official PHP  image from docker registry as my last choice. Thanks for link

Answer (score 0):

While php now comes with an [embedded webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), this webserver is not meant for production (as it can process only one HTTP request at any given time).

That is why you need to have a real web server side-by-side your php process in order to serve dynamic PHP pages.

Furthermore, the [PHP install guide](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php) list a web server as a prerequisite for compiling:

> Prerequisite knowledge and software for compiling:
>
> - Basic Unix skills (being able to operate "make" and a C compiler)
> - An ANSI C compiler
> - A web server
> - Any module specific components (such as GD, PDF libs, etc.)

Given those facts, you might want to reconsider trying to run apache and php on different machines when it comes to serve dynamic web pages.

Comment: Thanks for  links. Main intention is serve dynamic web content and other web stuff like session handling etc. So, according to you, there is no meaning to put efforts for separating apache & php when it comes to serve a dynamic web application ?

Comment: Exactly, PHP alone won't serve dynamic web pages